# Problema con NetBeans, No deja cambiar de direccion el jdk

Tags: java

Previamente había instalado la versión 8.1 pero por alguna razón no cargaba, así que lo desinstalé. Ahora instalé la versión 8.2 pero no me deja crear proyectos. He visto algunos vídeos en los que explican que hay que cambiar la dirección del jdk, pero al momento de cambiarlo no me permite guardarlo. Me dice que el administrador no lo permite. ¿Cómo lo arreglo?

Saludos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo mejor seria que colocaras unas imágenes de como quieres realizar el cambio así seria mas fácil poder darte una respuesta.

Comment: Ademas netbenas puede esar en JDK 11 y compilar un proyecto con otra, por ejemplo 8, eso se realiza con clic derecho sobre el proyecto `Build -> compiler -> java platform` y demás desde esa sección puedes agregar mas JDK.